# Net 7 XAPRAS7028 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'bin\Debug\net7.0\browser-wasm\App.dll' when referencing Blazor from MauiBlazor

Tags: .net, blazor, maui, maui-blazor, .net-7.0

I have two .net7 projects. A MauiBlazor project created with the default template and
a Blazor Web Assembly project created with the default template.

Inside the MauiBlazor project I added a reference to the Blazor project (I made all the necessary updates to reference the Blazor project as well)

The problem is when I try to run the MauiBlazor project, I get the following error:

```
Error   XAPRAS7028  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'MauiBlazor\BlazorApp\bin\Debug\net7.0\browser-wasm\BlazorApp.dll'.
```

**The question is, how can I reference a Blazor project from a Maui project?** Because adding a normal project reference is not working

```
<ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\BlazorApp\BlazorApp.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

I tried to publish the Blazor project with `dotnet publish -c Debug -o bin\Debug\net7.0\browser-wasm` but it didn't work.

I realized I can get it to work by manually copying the content of: `'MauiBlazor\BlazorApp\bin\Debug\net7.0\` to `MauiBlazor\BlazorApp\bin\Debug\net7.0\browser-wasm` and then run it with VS (command line won't work) but I'm sure there must be a better way.

I also created this project where the issue can be reproduced by trying to run the MauiMobileApp project. https://github.com/tico321/MauiReferenceBlazorIssue

Comment: What makes you think this should be possible? Can you provide a link to some discussion relevant to doing this? Unless I misunderstand what you are saying, a "Blazor Web Assembly" project is something that runs **inside a brower**. And Maui obviously does not run inside a browser. If you are targetting Windows only, I assume you can use Windows command line calls to "launch" the 2nd project. But that has nothing to do with Maui; its just standard Windows API calls, that you put in the `Windows` subfolder of your Maui project.

Comment: I thought that was the whole point of Maui Blazor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/maui?view=aspnetcore-6.0
It actually works fine to have both Blazor and Maui in the same project. The problem is when you split the blazor part to another project, but in the .Net conf they showed that it was possible. So I expect it to be possible

Comment: You can also take a look at this video for more context on what I'm trying to do https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnoCU5XGBh4

Comment: The "whole point" of Maui is to *re-use* your Blazor components' *source code*, so you don't need to rewrite them. This is not the same as being able to *build* the Web project, and then *reference* it from Maui. Your answer explains what is really going on; I've added a comment there.

Answer (score 1):

While answering a question above I found my answer as well.
If you want to share pages between Maui and Blazor you need a shared project. A great example of that is the [dotnet podcast repository](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnoCU5XGBh4) for more context on the repository and how they use blazor hybrid watch this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnoCU5XGBh4).

The repo I created to reproduce the issue was also updated with the solution https://github.com/tico321/MauiReferenceBlazorIssue

What I observed from the podcast repository is that the shared repo csproj file needs to reference the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` SDK and also the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web` package, so it should look like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Finally, be careful with the index.html file in Maui and in Blazor.
The blazor one needs this script `<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>` while the Maui one needs this one `<script src="_framework/blazor.webview.js" autostart="false"></script>`

Comment: OK, that makes sense. A "shared project" acts exactly as if the files were copied into the main project. It is equivalent to the advice I had previously seen, which is that the blazor components' source files should be added to the Maui project. Contrast this with a "library" project, which is built as a separate dll. It wasn't making sense to me to try to build a Blazor Web project as a separate entity, and then reference it from Maui. "shared project" avoids doing that.